# Conditional aggregation in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, aggregation

Consider the following matrix:

```
d <- data.frame(c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),c("a1","a1","a2","a2","a1","a1","a2","a2"),"c","d",c(1:8))
```

I want to aggregate the values in column 5, so I get the following data.frame:

```
d1 <- data.frame(c("a","a","b","b"),c("a1","a2","a1","a2"),"c","d",c(3,7,11,15))
```

That is, I want to aggregate the values in column 5 based on the names in column 2. So, I want to keep the names in column 1, 3 and 4 (in this case, the names in column 3 and 4 is the same, but in my case the vary).

How do I do that in R?

Comment: Show what you did so far

Comment: I have tried with: with(d, tapply(d[,1], d[,2], d[,3], d[,4], d[,5], sum)) - but that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

**Code**

```
require(data.table)
d[, .(unique(V3), unique(V4), sum(V5)), .(V1, V2)]
```

In specific, the syntax follows `dt[i, j, by]`. `i` declares the row subset of the `data.table` object, `j` declares a `list` (shorthand `.`) of operations you want to carry out on this subset, and `by` assigns grouping of the variables. In your case, you want to `sum` `V3` across `V1`-`V2` pairs. Furthermore, we apply `unique()` onto `V4` and `V5` in order to prevent duplicate rows.

**Result**

```
   V1 V2 V1 V2 V3
1:  a a1  c  d  3
2:  a a2  c  d  7
3:  b a1  c  d 11
4:  b a2  c  d 15
```

**Data**

```
d = data.table(V1 = c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"), 
                V2 = c("a1","a1","a2","a2","a1","a1","a2","a2"), 
                V3 = "c", 
                V4 = "d", 
                V5 = c(1:8))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`, you can do this by grouping the data by your id variables and then summarizing within those groups:

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
    group_by(v1, v2) %>%
    summarize(v3 = first(v3),
              v4 = first(v4),
              v5 = sum(v5))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   v1 [2]
  v1    v2    v3    v4       v5
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <int>
1 a     a1    c     d         3
2 a     a2    c     d         7
3 b     a1    c     d        11
4 b     a2    c     d        15
```

The calls to `first()` are just one way to arbitrarily get a single value for those columns where a value is repeated.